# Comment traduire “Après avoir fait un tour sur la plateforme” ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot

J'étais en train d'écrire un email et j'ai complètement bloqué sur la traduction de la phrase

> Après avoir fait un tour sur la plateforme

du français en anglais.

mais avec Google me donne ça 
[Google propose](https://translate.google.com/?hl=fr#fr/en/Apr%C3%A8s%20avoir%20fait%20un%20tour%20sur%20la%20plateforme)

Comment est-ce que je peux mieux traduire cette phrase ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about how to express something in the English language.

Comment: Try with https://www.deepl.com/translator

Comment: @cl-r: mauvais conseil dans ce cas précis. Sans contexte, le traducteur comprend la plateforme comme une plateforme physique sur laquelle on se balade.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez — En effet, il faut préciser : ensuite, cliquer sur le mot français *plateforme* pour afficher toutes les acceptions anglaises et faire de même dans la traduction pour vérifier que les propositions correspondent à ce que l’on souhaite exprimer

Comment: @jlliagre I have already found this kind of question in this community, so I do not know why you make it to close!!

Comment: J'ai voté pour fermer ta question car elle est hors sujet ici. S'il y en a d'autres similaires, elles auraient du l'être aussi. Si tu cherches à connaître une façon idiomatique d'écrire cette phrase en anglais, c'est sur English Language Learners ou English Language & Usage qu'il faut poser ta question, en expliquant le contexte et tes tentatives. Si ta question concerne vraiment le français,tu peux la modifier dans ce sens, par exemple en demandant les significations possibles de *faire un tour* et de *plate-forme* en français et demander sa réouverture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would translate it as

> After having made a tour on the site.

The past infinitif of french (avoir or être+infinitif) is usually interpeted it with the so-called perfect participle (having+-ing) when following a preposition.

https://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/participles_form.htm

https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/past-infinitive/

Comment: Les temps sont correct mais "take a ride" marche pas bien pour un site.

Comment: Je viens de modifier. Je n'ai pas vu que c'est pour Internet. Merci.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat merci pour votre aide